# Display some dynamic text on a UIButton

Tags: ios, uibutton, uiimagepickercontroller

My ViewController shows a button at the top.
The button is part of the view defined through Interface Builder and doesn't have any text on its label.
When the ViewController's view is shown, I set the text of the button in the following way:

```
[dButton setTitle:[NSLocalizedString( @"DeleteButton", @"" ) uppercaseString] forState: UIControlStateNormal];
dButton.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

The reason for doing this at runtime is to have the title taken from the appropriate internationalized strings file. The code above is invoked by the viewDidAppear:animated: method of my ViewController and it works as expected on a similar view.

The view where it doesn't work is the one where I show a UIImagePickerController upon loading so this might be the cause of my problem: does anybody know how to deal with it? I.e. How can I have the button shown with its text after the UIImagePickerController is closed?

-- EDIT

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {  
    [self setupDeleteButton];   
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    NSLog( @"Title is >%@<", dButton.titleLabel.text );
}
```

Comment: First question that immediately pops into my mind:
Do you have the IBOutlet set in IB? =P

Comment: Since it works fine in viewDidAppear:animated: on other views, can you post this specific viewDidAppear:animated in it's entirety (or as close to as possible?)  Maybe there's just a simple logic error that is being overlooked...

Comment: I added the viewDidAppear:animated: method, but I don't think it's something dealing with that. Notice that the setupDeleteButton body is simply the code posted originally.

Comment: I starting to have some doubts about the structure of the whole app: it is a tab based app with each tab represented by a CustomViewController-derived class. Within each CustomViewController I have a main controller (another instance of a CustomeViewController-derived class) containing in its turn two or more other sub-controllers. The difference between the two cases I mention above, is that in the case that's actually working, both sub-controllers are normal ones while in the case where the problem is showing up, one of them is a UIImagePickerController with overlays: does this make sense?

Comment: Had to draw it out, but yes, that makes sense, and I do believe you're right.  Is it possible that in this particular case the CustomViewController (the one where this particular `viewDidAppear:animated` is located) isn't firing?  I see you have an NSLog setup, does it show up in your console?  Have you tried breakpoints?

Comment: Yes, it is firing as expected but the text is not applied to the button - the console shows the log line. I also added a breakpoint but it seems it is never reached even though the log lines shows differently...

Comment: Afraid I'm at a loss.  I'll try and replicate the setup that you have based on the info you've given and see if I can get the same bug.  Will let you know.

Comment: Just curious now... how is the button setup? (ie, what kind of button is it, what properties does it have).  I just did a very basic template, and remember that the default button has a white background, and in your button setup you're setting the text label to white....

Comment: Ops! Thanks Geekswordsman, it seems we had the same hint at the same time!

Comment: Haha, always something simple!  Glad to be of help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved!
The UIButton I was using had been set up on Interface Builder with a 'Custom' Type and with an image on the 'Image' property while I should have set the image on the 'Background' property: the text was actually added to the button, but the Image property was covering it!

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the title in the viewWillAppear method.